# Android use enter key to navigate to next EditText with first letter capitalization

Tags: android, android-edittext

I know there are several posts about facilitating navigation between EditText fields. However, I can't get the suggested solutions to work and still have my EditTexts automatically have the first letter be capitalized. While setting the input type to "text" accomplishes what I want, if I set it to "textCapSentences", even using imeOptions, nextFocus, etc., I can't get the behavior I'm looking for.

Comment: try out this logic : when enter key is pressed the focus from the current EditText is removed and set to the next one (do it in a loop) and so on and as for the Capitalization on the first letter try out implementing this piece of code `myEditText.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT | InputType.TYPE_TEXT_FLAG_CAP_SENTENCES);`

Comment: Thanks @SígvardrÓlavrsson. I wound up having to set `android:inputType="textCapSentences"` and `android:singleLine="true"` in the layout xml.